# How to Execute script which is in JavaScript string variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have javascript variable like

```
 var str = "<!-- START Script Block for Chart Expense -->
   <div id='ExpenseDiv' align='center'>
    Chart.
   </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     var chart_Expense = new FusionCharts("../FusionCharts/FCF_Doughnut2D.swf", "Expense", "500", "350", "0", "0");
     chart_Expense.setDataXML("<graph caption='Expense' numberPrefix='' formatNumberScale='0' decimalPrecision='0'><set name='February' value='15.2' /><set name='April' value='716468.68' /><set name='May' value='541645.18' /><set name='June' value='681415.5' /><set name='July' value='575417.99' /><set name='August' value='436200.21' /><set name='September' value='159725' /><set name='November' value='0.53' /><set name='December' value='54.7' /></graph>");
     chart_Expense.render("ExpenseDiv");
      </script>
      <!-- END Script Block for Chart Expense -->"
```

I want to exequte this script in javascript side which is in the javascript string variable and append its result in one of the control in the page.
It means this string's script block have funvtion "chart_Expense.setDataXML" and "chart_Expense.render" , i want to exequte this function in client side.

my existing code is as below

**javascript side**

```
 function RebindChart() {
        var ddlChartType2Value = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlChartType2").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "DashBoardAccount.aspx/GetChatInfo",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: "{ charttype: '" + ddlChartType2Value + "' }",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FCLiteral2').innerHTML = result.d;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Server Side**

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetChatInfo(string charttype)
    {
        return BindExpense(charttype); // this function return string which is describe in above
    }
```

Comment: first you have to make it a valid string, unless the first snippet was just a sample. If it is, get rid of `var foo = "`

Comment: If you have the option of saving it in a separate js file you could use `$.getScript()` which is much easier to maintain, and save yourself the hassle of worrying about escaping single or double quotes everywhere.

Comment: It would probably be better to include (most of) the js code in the page as normal, and have your WebMethod return json containing all the data required to render the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can try eval()  see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp
But JSLINT will tell you not to use it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jQuery `.html()` to attach it to the DOM instead. It will evaluate and execute everything contained within your return string.

This works:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FCLiteral2').html(result.d);
```

This doesn't:

```
document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FCLiteral2').innerHTML = result.d;
```

As shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/66Lcg/1/)

```
$(function () {

    // jQuery
    var resultJQ = "<script>alert('jQuery'); $('body').append('jQuery');<\/script>";
    $('body').append($('<div>').attr('id', 'scriptjq'));
    $('#scriptjq').html(resultJQ);

    // Javascript
    var resultJS = "<script>alert('Javascript'); $('body').append('Javascript');<\/script>";
    $('body').append($('<div>').attr('id', 'scriptjs'));
    document.getElementById('scriptjs').innerHTML = resultJS;

});
```

Hope it helps!